# Sum of a column in Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Im trying to make an Excel file from an Access query. I need to calculate the amount for each column in the resulting table and add them to the last row as SUM. I transferd a table from queries to Excel sheet, but I can not add the amount. Is it possible to use the VBA inside Access to find the height of a column and add the sum of the column to the next cell?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to work in this way? You can create a query in Access, and in Excel, choose to import data from that MS-Access database (I believe it's possible to choose the query from which you want to import), and once imported in Excel, you can add the sum at the end using standard Excel featurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to do any job with functions in excel you could simply do it in the sql query in access and choose to export the query result. Here is an example:

[image]

```
SELECT Table1.[ID], Table1.[Field1], Table1.[Field2]
FROM Table1
union all
SELECT 'sum', sum(Table1.[Field1]), sum(Table1.[Field2])
FROM Table1;
```

[image]